# Add new item based on count c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, foreach

I have a use case where I have to add a insert item for a given key only if it satisfies the count(i.e already existing items for that key which is 2)

e.g I have 2 keys and for these 2 keys I can add only 2 items in each key. But first key need to be filled first(i.e when it contains 2 items) then only move to the next key to add the new item.
If both the keys have 2 items no data will be inserted.

Below is my code:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,int>();// This dictionary contains the key and its count(helps to  check for which key to insert data)

var keys = new List<string> {"key1","key2"};//List of keys available

string keyToBeUsed = string.Empty;
                foreach (var key in keys)
                {
                    if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
                    {
                        keyToBeUsed = key;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (dict[key] < 2)
                        {
                            keyToBeUsed = key;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

**keyToBeUsed** will be used for which new item will be added.

I am new to C# is there a better way to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: You never add anything to `dict`

Comment: @KlausGütter: dict will have updated data containing key and its count. i havent added the data but the key and its count data will be fetched from the db and stored in the dict. so then everytime a new item needs to be added using dict we can get the latest count for each key to decide which for which key data needs to be added

Comment: OK, this was not clear that `dict` is already populated somewhere. So what is then your problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
            foreach (var key in keys)
            {
                int count;
                if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out count) || count < 2)
                {
                    keyToBeUsed = key;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

If you can't get the key (key not exists) or the getted value (count) is less than 2, you must insert in that key. You can add in the dictionary in the foreach and remove the keyToBeUsed:

```
            foreach (var key in keys)
            {
                int count;
                if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out count) || count < 2)
                {
                    dict[key] = count + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
```